# Data race? segfault, but where is the issue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, crash

There following simple program crashes occasionally, but I don't understand what can be worong with it?

It's compiled with '-pthread -std=c++11 -g -O2 -pie -fpie -std=c++11'
valgrind drd reports a data race, but I can't see why.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

bool running;
pthread_rwlock_t _rwlock;

class Dummy {
public:
    Dummy() : _refs(0) {
        Ref();
    }
    volatile int _refs;

    void Ref() {
        ++_refs;
    }
    void Unref() {
        --_refs;
        if (_refs <= 0) {
            delete this;
        }
    }
};

static Dummy* s_dummy;

Dummy* get_dummy() {
    pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&_rwlock);
    Dummy* ret = s_dummy;
    ret->Ref();
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&_rwlock);
    return ret;
}

void *work1(void*) {
    while (running) {
        Dummy* new_dummy = new Dummy();
        pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&_rwlock);
        Dummy* to_del = s_dummy;
        s_dummy = new_dummy;
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&_rwlock);
        to_del->Unref();
    }
}

void *work2(void*) {
    while (running) {
        Dummy* p = get_dummy();
        p->Unref();
    }
}

int main() {
    running = true;
    pthread_rwlock_init(&_rwlock, NULL);
    s_dummy = new Dummy();
    pthread_t threads[2];

    threads[0] = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, work1, NULL);
    threads[0] = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, work2, NULL);

    sleep(30);
    running = false;

    void* ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], &ret);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `threads[0] = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, work2, NULL);` be `threads[1] = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, work2, NULL);`?

Comment: Actually the two assignments to `threads[0]` should be removed and you should just call `pthread_create()` if you don't want to check for errors because the assignment will destroy the thread identifyer written by the function.

Comment: A data race on `_refs`I presume? Could you add the message given?

Comment: Are you running this on a different processor than x86, by any chance? Say, ARM? If so, I suspect your caches on the different cores aren't properly synchronized.

Comment: i mean the _refs caused segfault，data race，but how can this happen?

Comment: @bugsking: What system is this running on?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the exact message you're getting since you didn't add it, however you at least have a data race on `_refs` and it may cause a double `delete`.

As an example, both threads can be inside `Unref` on the same object at the same time with _refs initially == 2.

Let's say both threads run `--_refs`, the value of `_refs` will then be 0. Then both threads check if `refs` is zero, and since `_refs` is volatile they both read the value 0 from memory and both delete.

What you probably want for `_refs` is an *atomic* variable, not a volatile.

Answer (score 0):

The two unrefs in work1 and work2 can conflict. There is nothing stopping a delete from happening in both threads simultaneously.

Also, you should make `running` volatile, or better yet, atomic.

Finally, it seems an aweful lot of work for something that could trivially be solved using a shared_ptr. The code below is equivalent to yours:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

class Dummy {
};

std::atomic<bool> running = true;
static std::shared_ptr<Dummy> s_dummy = std::make_shared<Dummy> ();

void work1 () {
    while (running)
        s_dummy = std::make_shared<Dummy> ();
}

void work2 () {
    while (running) 
        s_dummy = nullptr;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1 (work1);
    std::thread t2 (work2);

    sleep (30);
    running = false;

    t1.join ();
    t2.join ();

    return 0;
}
```